# Plot FFT of incoming data (via bluetoothchat )

Tags: android, bluetooth, fft

http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/9103/overalle.jpg

Well the problem I have is that I am getting the waveform to be diplayed via Bluetooth chat on the screen but I have no idea how to also plot its FFT ..

Can anyone just let me know if it is possible to plot FFt of incoming UART via Bluetooth. 
and if yes just a few steps how to do it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are braver than I. Yes, it is possible.

1. Find a good library to take the FFT of the data you are receiving.

   - Consider doing the processing in your processing unit. This will make updates harder to push, but will *greatly* reduce your apps battery strain.
   - Consider using the NDK, this is a lot of computation and if you want it to be realtime the NDK might be your best bet.
2. Use a plotting library. There are many of these, and rolling your own really isn't hard.
3. For the love of god, do not rely on this system when health is concerned. Android is **not** certified or guaranteed in any way. Please use your app as a diagnostics tool only.

This answer is pretty vague and tautological, but that's because your question is pretty vague. Are there any specific problems you are running into?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am right now working on the signal processing hardware and the visualization of the waveform part. I have no idea how to proceed with NDK. But I will surely look into it and find out a solution. I have got my answer. Only wanted to know if it is possible to implement it . Thanks a ton.